# Setting a start position in a Path(Batch processing)

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

i'm a newbie in batch scripting,started learning this from last week only and this is the first question that i'm asking here.here is my situation,
Consider this example,this lists all directories under D:/Jose/test1 and append this to a text file.

Code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /d D:\Jose\test1
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /ad /on /s /b') DO (
ECHO %%~pG%%~nG>>D:\test2\list.txt
)
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Text file output :

- \Jose\test1\1
- \Jose\test1\2
- \Jose\test1\1\12
- \Jose\test1\1\13
- \Jose\test1\1\12\131
- \Jose\test1\1\12\Copy of 131
- \Jose\test1\1\12\131\1311
- \Jose\test1\1\12\131\1311\13111
- \Jose\test1\1\12\131\1311\13112
- \Jose\test1\1\12\Copy of 131\1311
- \Jose\test1\1\12\Copy of 131\1311\13111
- \Jose\test1\1\12\Copy of 131\1311\13112
- \Jose\test1\1\13\132
- \Jose\test1\1\13\132\1321
- \Jose\test1\1\13\132\1321\13211

I want to remove '\jose' from all line ie, i want to set '\test1' as the starting path. Need help guys..Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
for /d /r %%G in (*) do sed -r "s/^\\[^\]+(\\.*)/\1/" "%%~pnxG">>D:\test2\list.txt
```

---

..solution with *pure batch*:

```
@echo off &setlocal
(FOR /f "tokens=2* delims=\" %%a IN ('dir /ad /on /s /b') DO ECHO(\%%~b)>D:\test2\list.txt
TYPE D:\test2\list.txt
PAUSE
```

..and more *batch*:

```
@echo off &setlocal
(FOR /d /r %%G in (*) DO (
     SET "fname=%%~G"
     SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
     SET "fname=!fname:*\Jose=!"
     ECHO(!fname!
     ENDLOCAL
))>D:\test2\list.txt
TYPE D:\test2\list.txt
PAUSE
```

Comment: this looks good,but i'm working on xp and i'm not alowed to install anything and cannot ask my client to do so..is there any alternative method using basic batch processing?

Comment: Thanks...this worked..but i had to change '%%~a' to '%%~G' and "fname=!fname:\Jose=!" to "fname=!fname:D:\Jose=!"

Comment: @JoseAntony I made a shorter version, you can try this.

Comment: tested it again, it works here. Have you forgot the `*` asterisk?

Comment: @enduro .. now this works too..thanks..but the first answer was much suited to my requirement(i already copied that)..you should edit and add that too for others.. :-)